# res.end не оканчивает запрос

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

есть скрипт:

```
app.get('/:userId', function(req, res) {
    var userId = +req.params.userId;

    users.forEach(function (user) {
        if (user.user_id === userId) {
        console.log(1);
            res.send('<h1>' + user.username + '</h1>' + '<h2> Id: ' + user.user_id  + '</h2>');
            res.end();
        }
    });

    console.log(2);

    res.send('user with id: ' + userId + ' not found');
    res.end();
});
```

когда выполняется запрос, то в консоль выводится 1 и 2, почему, ведь res.end должен закончить запрос и сработать как return; или не так ?

Если пользователь найден то вернется он и в консоль выведется 1, а если нет, то выведется 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `res.end();` завершает ответ на запрос, а не выполняет выход из функции.

Можно сделать так:

```
app.get('/:userId', function(req, res) {
  var userId = +req.params.userId;

  for (user of users) {
    if (user.user_id === userId) {
      console.log(1);
      res.send('<h1>' + user.username + '</h1>' + '<h2> Id: ' + user.user_id  + '</h2>');
      res.end();
      return;
    }
  }

  console.log(2);
  res.send('user with id: ' + userId + ' not found');
  res.end();
});
```

И ещё вариант:

```
app.get('/:userId', function(req, res) {
  var userId = +req.params.userId;

  var found = users.some(function (user) {
    if (user.user_id === userId) {
      console.log(1);
      res.send('<h1>' + user.username + '</h1>' + '<h2> Id: ' + user.user_id  + '</h2>');
      return true;
    }
  });

  if (!found) {
    console.log(2);
    res.send('user with id: ' + userId + ' not found');
  }

  res.end();
});
```

Comment: то есть каждый раз придется писать return после res.end ? и никак это не обойти ? https://jsfiddle.net/sju8werg/

Comment: @Виталий, а что мешает просто воспользоваться циклом? Особенно, недавно добавленным for-of.

Comment: @Виталий, и ещё один вариант добавил.